# Debug log Operation column "/services/data..."

Tags: debug-logs

We have an update that happens on leads and we are trying to understand what is the source.
i looked at the debug logs and saw the following info:

[image]

What does "/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/Lead/00Q4I00000dmQFdUAM" mean under Operation? Is there any way i can find out what is the source of this update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Application is not specified, so it's not the Apex Data Loader, SFDX CLI, or any other official tool (including the Workbench). We do know it's using the REST API (/services/data), using API 26.0 (v26.0), and it's performing a Lead update (/Lead/{recordId}). However, without an identifying Client string, we simply have no idea. It could be a NodeJS script, some unofficial third-party software, a Visualforce page, etc. There's really no way to know aside from, say, Freezing the user that's performing the updates and wait for someone to complain that an integration stopped working.

Comment: Thank you very much! i think we narrowed it down to a 3rd part app that we connected a while ago.

Comment: If we are using an integration - is there a way we can define\send the identifying client string?

Comment: The client can specify a string to identify itself. See the [CallOptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/headers_calloptions.htm) header.